# Raspberry Pi and DoorBell Video Camera

Tags: video

Is it possible to integrate RPI 3 Model B+ with Intercom like this https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Xinsilu-V70F-M2-7-Inch-Color-Video-Door-Phone-Intercom-Doorbell-System-HD-IR-Camera-Doorphone/32694798040.html?scm=1007.13339.33317.0&pvid=03ad3864-848b-4a9f-9b27-83f3e869a8cd&tpp=1 ?

I plan to receive signal from DoorBell Panel [image]
 or from socket on Intercom [image]

by using USB EasyCap converter like this https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-Black-USB-2-0-Video-Capture-Card-Converter-PC-Adapter-TV-Audio-DVD/32674311344.html?detailNewVersion=&categoryId=200001096 .

Is it possible?

I think, that intercoms DoorBell panel like this use PAL/NTSC video.

Am I wrong?

Comment: have you managed to solve this? I have the exact same intercom, and was looking for similar solution.

Comment: Hi. Yep, I did. Just used 5...15 USB CCTV converter from AliExpress, EasyCap

Comment: Do you have wiring scheme? But this is just one way, you get video feed, but cannot talk? What software did you use on raspberry pi side?

Answer (score 2):

If the doorbell camera generates PAL or NTSC the EasyCAP dongle will be able to decode the signal.

So, yes.

I haven't personally used an EasyCap on the Pi though so I don't know if the display will be jerky.  I have used EasyCap to view the Pi's composite output on a Linux laptop.

Comment: OK, but how can I check, what type of video signals this intercom generates? May be some standards for China intercoms? There is no info about this on intercom.

Comment: Find the specs for the camera or ask the manufacturer.

Comment: ))) And no another simple way? It's Chinese ))) Sellers have not any specs or info from manufacterers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is NTSC.  Video signal was listed as 1 VP-P.  This [page](http://www.broadcaststore.com/pdf/model/793698/TT148%20-%204053.pdf) describes it as a NTSC Composite signal.  It should work with the EasyCAP.